# ./node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35865:17-40 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '_http_common'

Tags: angular, express, angular-universal, prisma

I'm using angular universal with express-engine, the build for server fails with this error message:

./node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35865:17-40 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '_http_common' in 'C:\Users\jude\Documents\Portfolio\evaluation-system\evaluation-system-app\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some google research, i figured out how to fix this bug:

1. install custom-webpack ( npm install @angular-builders/custom-webpack --save-dev )
2. update angular.json file by doing the following:
   **replace this:**

   "server": {
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
   .
   .
   .
   }

   **to this**

   "server": {
   "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
   }
3. update the options section in the server

   "server": {
   "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
   "options": {
   .
   .
   .
   "customWebpackConfig": {
   "path": "./webpack.config.js"
   }
   }
4. Now create a new file at the root of you app with name "webpack.config.js"
5. inside webpack.config.js add these

   module.exports = {
   externals: ["_http_common", "encoding"],
   };

That's it. I hope this helps. happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

### Use [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals):

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  ...
  externals: [ nodeExternals() ],
  ...
}
```